# How to display an event appearing after a period of time (gap) in use-case realization diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case

i`m wondering what is the way to display an event which appears after some period of time on a use-case realization diagram. For example lets say an actor taps a display of his smart phone, the display turns on and in 5 minutes it turns off. Is it allowed in UML to write a message on event like "DisplayOFF(5min)",if not, what is most proper way?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "use-case realization diagram"? UML use case diagrams are unaware of sequence flows. It is also quite solution-independent, because it is rather meant to show objectives of a system. Have a look at UML sequence diagrams and check whether or not they satisfy your prescribed need.